# Unable to create .bin directory in CIFS

Tags: ubuntu, mkdir, bin, cifs

I discovered this issue working with nodejs on a remote FS (cifs). Everything works fine but creating ".bin" directory an error appeared "unable to create directory .bin". All others dirs' names are accepted (.bin2, .blabla, ...). Same behavior on other CIFS mouting point. Anyone knows why and how to solve?

Answer (score 1):

Exactly the same thing happens to me, I set up a CIFS directory (WD EXT2), and when I ran an rsync, it reported that the `mkdir /\<some path\>/.bin` gives the error:

> No such file or directory (2)

Trying to do the `mkdir .bin` on the command line in the mounted directory gives me the same error.

A workaround, is to create the directory manually on the remote server.

Comment: Yes, but if you create the dir remotely than you are able to see it when mounted?